# How do you discover who funded a study?

Tags: research-process

Someone asked a similar question here: [How to find out who funded a study / research?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/56959/how-to-find-out-who-funded-a-study-research?newreg=065470fd33814350848e37f287cd9696)

several years ago, but not a single person had a real answer. So perhaps now. So...how? How do I find information on who funded a certain company or where their funds might come from in general? Specifically trying to find information on this company: https://ridgebackbio.com/

Thank you in advance.

PS: not looking to be spoon-fed information on this company, but to learn this skill on following money. I just can't find any resources to learn it in the first place.

Comment: Maybe this would be a more appropriate question on one of the finance SE sites?

Answer (score 4):

To answer the "who funds a company" question, which is not the same as "who funds a study":

Real biotech companies are usually pretty easy to get information on. Take [Editas](https://www.crunchbase.com/organization/editas-medicine) for example. Lots of information there about funding cause it's a real company and it helps make investors less nervous when there's transparency (and they can see other real investors have skin in the game).

[Your example](https://www.crunchbase.com/organization/ridgeback-biotherapeutics) has no public information because it's not a real biotech company. It's a shell company that's brokering IP in a way that probably relies on "Political connections", which often means something that is poorly distinguishable from bribery. Any public information is just more ammo for a US attorney if they start poking around.

Answer (score 3):

I upvoted the other answer, but I'd also like to say that many papers and articles will have an acknowledgement of their funding source either in the Introduction or a separate Acknowledgments section because countries I'm familiar with the funding agencies require resulting publications to acknowledge their support of the underlying studies they fund. NSF and NIH require this in the US, and then require you to say that you did so when you report the publication back to them later.

Corporate money can be much less restrictive in the way that it is given. A company may ask, in my experience, for nothing more than a royalty-free license to the resulting work and no acknowledgement of the funding at all. They may just want you to tout the funding and nothing more. The good PR may be all they really want for the money. Sometimes the company just wants to write a check and give a simple gift with no strings attached and try to do some good in the world as long as everyone gets a shot as using the results.

Answer (score 2):

I do not disagree with the prior answers as general answers.

Virtually all biomedical journals require disclosure of all sources of funding or a statement that the research did not have a source of funding.  Finding the source of funding for a published study is generally easy.

I also agree that the question of the source of funding for companies is quite difficult unless the company is publicly traded.

Many biotechnology companies first exist as (usually) small “start-ups” seeking to bring to market one product or to develop a line of products from some kind of technology platform (e.g., monoclonal antibodies, mRNA).  The funding for such companies is often private equity—money that comes from rich people who have money to spare.  Some of these people fund the company directly (they write a check to the company) and some people fund the company through investment in a private equity firm.

The WIKIPEDIA has an extensive description of what private firms are, how they raise money and provide funding, and how they make money.

The following is an excerpt:

“A private-equity firm is an investment management company that provides financial backing and makes investments in the private equity of startup or operating companies through a variety of loosely affiliated investment strategies including leveraged buyout, venture capital, and growth capital. Often described as a financial sponsor, each firm will raise funds that will be invested in accordance with one or more specific investment strategies.”

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Private-equity_firm

But the government, private foundations and large pharmaceutical companies may also be sources of funding for these “start up” companies.

It is extremely difficult (maybe almost impossible) to determine which individuals are providing money to these start-ups and it is generally difficult to determine what people (or entities) are giving money to a private equity firm **UNLESS** the company wants to make this information available or makes it available through their communications and press releases.

In my experience, reading a company’s press releases is the best way to glean information about the source of funding for a company, noting that the sources of funding may change over time.

For Ridgeback Biotherapeutics LP, a December 22, 2019 press release contains much information about how development of one of its products—a monoclonal antibody used to treat Ebola—was funded.

https://www.businesswire.com/news/home/20201222005421/en/

“About Ebanga:

Ebanga™ (ansuvimab-zykl, formerly referred to as mAb114) is a monoclonal antibody isolated from a human survivor of the 1995 Ebola outbreak in Kikwit, a city in the DRC. Nancy Sullivan, Ph.D., Chief of the Biodefense Research Section at the NIAID, VRC and her team, alongside scientists from VIR Biotechnology’s Humabs BioMed S.A. subsidiary, discovered that the survivor retained antibodies against Ebola 11 years after infection. The team isolated the antibodies, tested the most favorable ones in both laboratory and nonhuman primate studies, and selected ansuvimab as the most promising among the set for clinical trial. Professor Jean-Jacques Muyembe-Tamfum, Director General of DRC’s INRB and one of the scientists involved in the original detection of the Ebola virus in 1976, played a key role in discovering Ebanga. **Ebanga development has been funded in whole or in part with federal funds from the Department of Health and Human Services; Office of the Assistant Secretary for Preparedness and Response; Biomedical Advanced Research and Development Authority, under Contract Numbers 75A50119C00059 and 75A50120C00009**.” [bolded for emphasis]

The same press release contains information about the funding of the company in general.

“Headquartered in Miami, Florida, Ridgeback Biotherapeutics LP is a biotechnology company focused on emerging infectious diseases. Ridgeback markets EbangaTM for the treatment of Ebola and has a late-stage development pipeline which includes molnupiravir for the treatment of COVID-19. Development of molnupiravir **is entirely funded by Ridgeback Biotherapeutics and Merck & Co. All equity capital in Ridgeback Biotherapeutics, LP originated from Wayne and Wendy Holman,** who are committed to investing in and supporting medical technologies that will save lives.” [Bolded for emphasis]

A May 30, 2019 press release is posted at the company’s website.
https://www.prnewswire.com/news-releases/ridgeback-biotherapeutics-lp-announces-orphan-drug-designation-for-mab114-300859467.html

This press release contains a link to Ridgeback Capital.

https://www.ridgebackcap.com/

Ridgeback Capital is described as follows:

“Ridgeback Capital is a private investment company that is focused on investing in life science companies. Ridgeback was started in 2006 by Wayne Holman, MD. Dr. Holman and his team seek long term investments in private and public companies that are creating life-saving and life changing technologies.”